# JavaScript - Loop through an array of image directories and apply them to an image

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have an array containing a few values, each one of them is an image location on a website.

```
["img/image1.png", "img/image2.png", "img/image3.png", "img/image4.png"]
```

I need to loop through them and apply them as a `src` attribute to an image sequentially every second, image1 then image2, image3 and etc...
I Really want to use a `for` loop but I have compleately no idea where to start...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think a `for` loop applies here because of the asynchronous nature of what you want.

Let's think about the behaviour:

```
# psuedocode

choose the next image
set image src

when the image has loaded
   wait one second

loop from line #1
```

Implementing that logic

```js
const images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/150", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x50", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x100", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x25"]

const image = document.querySelector('#image')

let currentImage = 0

function updateImage() {
  // choose the next image
  const newImageSrc = images[currentImage++ % images.length]

  // set image src
  image.src = newImageSrc

  // when the image has loaded
  image.onload = function () {
    // wait one second (1000 milliseconds) and "loop"
    setTimeout(updateImage, 1000)
  }
}

// start with an image immediately without waiting
updateImage()
```

```html
<img id="image">
```

Other answers here have used `setInterval`. It's my opinion that you should avoid `setInterval` as much as possible, and use a `setTimeout` with a self-referencing loop.

consider

```
function doSomethingIntesive() {
  ...
}

setInterval(doSomethingIntesive, 1000)
```

you want to call `doSomethingIntensive` every second. What happens if it takes more than 1 second to execute `doSomethingIntensive`? In your case, `doSomethingIntensive` would be "download the image and show it". Over slow connections, it's definitely possible for it to take more than 1 second.

now consider

```
function doSomethingIntensive() {
    ...
    setTimeout(doSomethingIntensive, 1000)
}

setTimeout(doSomethingIntensive, 1000) // or just doSomethingIntensive() if you don't want the initial wait
```

This code with do the intensive operation in its entirety *then* queue a new invocation of the intensive function. You end up with much more consistent behaviour.

a nifty trick is to use a "virtual" image to download the image before applying it to the real dom element - taking advantage of browser caching.

```js
const images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/150", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x50", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x100", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x25"]

const image = document.querySelector('#image')

let currentImage = 0

const vImage = new Image()

function updateImage() {
    // choose the next image
    const newImageSrc = images[currentImage++ % images.length]

    vImage.onload = function() {
        image.src = newImageSrc

        /* this should be instant but it's still good
         * practice to always use the onload event handler */
        image.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(updateImage, 1000)
        }
    }

    vImage.src = newImageSrc
}

updateImage()
```

```html
<img id="image">
```

open up your browser's dev tools and enable connection throttling. The first image might take a while to show up, but you'll never have an empty (no) image showing. ...although that might be beyond what you need for this.

Comment: I only need it to run at most 256x images as a frame by freme animation.
One funny thing is that somehow I can not pass a variable containing a target image to change it's `.src` attribute when using `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`...

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. They have the same signature (neither of them accept arguments, actually).

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout), this will run a function in `x milliseconds`.

```js
const images = ["https://via.placeholder.com/150", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x50", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x100", "https://via.placeholder.com/150x25"]

// Get the image reference
const img = document.querySelector('#my-image')
// Add an event to listen for when it loads and trigger the next change
img.onload = () => setTimeout(changeImage, 1000)

// A counter to count the times we change images
let counter = 0

function changeImage() {
  // Set the image src
  // We will get the modulus value
  // Using this the number will never be larger than the length
  img.src = images[counter++ % images.length]
}

changeImage()
```

```html
<img id="my-image">
```

(added by geuis) Alternate setInterval example since the questioner may not have a high level understanding of js:

```
let counter = 0

setInterval(() => { 
  img.src = images[counter % images.length];
  counter++;
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I would argue that a self-referencing `setTimeout` is more applicable given you'll be spending time on I/O loading the image

Comment: Okay I have changed it to reflect your suggestion.

Comment: You won't be spending much time at all on i/o past the first round of image loading. Everything's cached after that. @GetOffMyLawn your original version was better.

Comment: "past the first round of image loading" is not a good justification for a poor user experience... what if there are hundreds of possible images? or they endlessly cycle (pulling from an API, for example). What if the user is on 3G? What if the images are huge?

Comment: Both methods are good if it comes to my problem. I only need this to run a small library for a frame-by-frame animation which would display at most 256x images.